# How to get the second to last email in outlook with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

I am currently trying to get the second to last email in an outlook folder. I am able to get the last email with the following code.

However I want to get the one previous to that.

I have searched several forums and I am yet to find an answer to this. I dont want to do a loop since my code already is doing a lot of tasks!

Thank you in advance

```
messages = archiveFolder1.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what packages you are using.

Comment: Second to last to what order? The Items collection is unsorted unless you explicitly call Items.Sort and provide the property to sort on and its direction. The sort you see in the Explorer list in Outlook is not the same as returned by the Items collection (unsorted).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I was using win32com.client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook has a method for this .GetPrevious(), call it after .GetLast() and it should return the next-to-last message.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.getprevious